# Get only the date from a datetime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass a date in a viewbag like this

```
DateTime? DueDate = this.dbContext.OBProcessMonitors.Where(o => o.EmployeeID 
== GlobalVariables.EmployeeID).First().DueDate;
        ViewBag.DueDate = DueDate;
```

WHen i call the viewbag in razor `@viewbag.duedate` i get the date and time.  How can I get just the date out of it?

Comment: `if (DueDate.HasValue) ViewBag.DueDate = DueDate.Value.Date;`

Comment: Error 50 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found

Comment: I missed the fact that it is nullable. Please see the update.

Comment: If you want to format it the same, regardless of the culture info, you can use something like `DueDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Thank you Jacob Roberts. This works

Answer (score 0):

Use 'DueDate.Value.Date' to get just the date of a datetime.

Comment: If i do this in controller or in razor it still shows date and time.

Comment: DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need a date string, not a date object. So do following

To get short date string: like "6/15/2009" in en-US

```
Value.ToShortDateString()
```

Or to get long date string: like "Monday, June 15, 2009"

```
Value.ToLongDateString()
```

Or using custom format

```
Value.ToString("d")
```

Check other formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `DateTime` to string and format it however you want to:

```
ViewBag.TheDate = yourobject.DueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") //or,
ViewBag.TheDate = yourobject.DueDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") //or,
ViewBag.TheDate = yourobject.DueDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") //etc...
```